# How can I open a port on my public IP with my router?

Tags: router, ip, port-forwarding, ip-address, dmz

I am trying to port forward a port on my IP. Unfortunately, my router (Sagemcom F@st 5657 interface) only lets me open ports on my private IP, which is useless if I want to connect from other computers. I have DMZ.

I checked if the port was open on https://ismyportopen.com/, and it wasn't, which is obvious because I can only use my public IP to check.

**How can I open a port on my public IP?**

Comment: What you saying makes little sense.  I wonder if you are behind Carrier Grade NAT - in which case you cant.

Comment: So I have to change my NAT type to be able to open a public ip port?

Comment: No - you need to ask or buy from your ISP a static IP address.

Comment: Oh, I thought I could change to static IP directly from my PC.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html)?

Comment: No, the port is already open in firewall

Comment: @Alex12 make a scan with nmap. It finds vulnerabilities in your network. It might find a already open port.

Comment: You cannot open ports if your behind a carrier grade NAT…

Comment: You should start off by establishing if you are behind CGNAT.  What does YOUR ROUTER report its WAN IP as being? (If you are worried about privacy, you can just provide the first 2 octets - eg 100.10.x.x

Comment: From what I know, I have cgnat